# Como muestro una notificación en primer plano para cualquier dispositivo

Tags: typescript, next.js, firebase-messaging, pwa, service-workers

Tengo un proyecto de next js con typescript el cual esta destinado a ser una pwa para lo cual decidí usar FCM de firebase para las push notifications, estuve probando la app ya en un entorno para ver su funcionamiento ante un celular, el problema que me ha surgido es el siguiente: firebase tiene dos funciones para manejar esto, la primera es en segundo plano y la otra en primer plano, el problema se me dio en la funcion de primer plano, pondré el código y explico mas después del código

```
// Función para solicitar permiso de notificación y obtener el token
async function requestPermission() {
  
  const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

  if (permission === "granted") {

    

    const app = initializeApp({
      //omito las credenciales pero son correctas
    });

    const messaging = getMessaging(app);

    // Manejar los mensajes de notificación en primer plano
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {

      const title = payload.data?.title as string;
      const body = payload.data?.body as string;

      if ("Notification" in window && Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // new Notification(title, { body, });
        self.registration.showNotification(title, { body, });
      }

    });

    try {
      const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: "aqui tambien omitire",
      });

      if (currentToken) {
        setTokenPush(currentToken);
      } else {
        console.log("Can not get token");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error getting token:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Do not have permission!");
  }
}
```

El problema es en la función **onMessage**, en el código hay una linea comentada la cual es **new Notification(title, { body, });** esta linea funciona bien y muestra la notificación pero solo en desktop (laptops, computadoras etc) cuando la probé con celulares me salta el error de que es **illegal invocation** usar new Notification(...) y me recomendaba usar ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification(...), el problema es que trate de usar eso y typescript no me deja me sigue saliendo esto
[image: Error de la funcion]

he probado también otras cosas, como usar self.registration.showNotification(..) y declarar registration en un archivo .d.ts (ya que typescript no lo soporta), alguna idea de que puedo usar para que muestre la notificación sin importar que tipo de dispositivo es? o alguna alternativa viable.